# How to use a variable value as part of a variable name in python?

Tags: python

I was wondering if there was a way to have a variable value as part of another variable name in python. I have my code here, but I think there should be a way to make it a lot cleaner:

```py
if self.player.dir == 'UP':
    self.player.image = self.player.image_up[0]
if self.player.dir == 'DOWN':
    self.player.image = self.player.image_down[0]
if self.player.dir == 'LEFT':
    self.player.image = self.player.image_left[0]
if self.player.dir == 'RIGHT':
    self.player.image = self.player.image_right[0]
```

I was thinking if we could have the value of `dir` as part of the `self.player.image_(dir)[0]`. I am not sure how I would do this though. It would look something like this I think:

```py
self.player.image = self.player.image_(dir)[0]
```

Comment: This is a good use case for a dict

Comment: @robinsax How would I go about doing that?

Comment: Use the key names as keys and the images as values

Answer (score 4, accepted):

something like this might be what you are looking for:

```
images = {
    "UP": self.player.image_up[0],
    "DOWN": self.player.image_down[0],
    "RIGHT": self.player.image_right[0],
    "LEFT": self.player.image_left[0]
}

self.player.image = images[self.player.dir]
```

Answer (score 2):

Using Python dictionary might be what you re looking for

```
self.player.image_ = {
     'UP':self.player.image_up[0],
     'DOWN': self.player.image_down[0],
     'LEFT':self.player.image_left[0],
     'RIGHT': self.player.image_right[0]
}
self.player.image = self.player.image_[self.player.dir]
```